# Undefined method 'should' when using .text.include? with watir and ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to verify text on a web page. 
The line of code using is: `@browser.test.include?('Favorites').should==true`

When the script executes this line I get the error: `undefined method 'should' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)`

Here is the full code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'    
require 'rspec'


@browser=Watir::Browser.new :ff
@browser.goto('http://enoteca.demo.episerver.com/en-US/')
@browser.link(:text=>'Register').wait_until_present
@browser.text.include?("Favorites").should==true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an [example group](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it) that contains one or more examples.  For instance:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

describe "an example group" do 
  it "is an example" do
    browser = Watir::Browser.new 
    browser.goto('www.example.org')
    browser.text.include?('Domain').should==true
  end
end
```

If you place the above in a file ending with `_spec.rb` (e.g. `foo_spec.rb`), you can run it at command line or terminal: `rspec foo_spec.rb`.  After completion, rspec will return a status:

```
Finished in X.XX seconds (files took X.XXXX seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Also, the `should` method has been deprecated in rspec3 (although it will still work for now).  In fact, rspec3 will return a deprecation warning if you use `should`.

> Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly
>   enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead.

Here's the same spec as above but using `expect` instead of `should`:

```
describe "an example group" do 
  it "is an example" do
    browser = Watir::Browser.new 
    browser.goto('www.example.org')
    expect(browser.text).to include 'Domain' # expect method instead of should
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would think you should be using an example group (as @orde mentioned), it is not technically required. You can use the expectations outside an example group by including the `RSpec::Expectations`:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'    
require 'rspec'

# Include the expectations so that they do not need an example group
include RSpec::Expectations

@browser=Watir::Browser.new :ff
@browser.goto('http://enoteca.demo.episerver.com/en-US/')
@browser.link(:text=>'Register').wait_until_present
@browser.text.include?("Favorites").should==true
```